# Why does an online compiler reject this VLA code, but local Apple clang doesn't?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, apple-clang

I'm following an exercise in which I have to prove the difference between C and C++ constant expressions. It is valid to write something like this in C++:

```
const int size_1 = 2;
const int size_2 = 2;

const int arr[size_1 + size_2] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

int main() {
  return arr[0];
}
```

but I would expect that it would throw an error when copied to .c file and compiled in C - in fact I've used online compiler to check it and it returned:

```
main.c:6:11: error: variably modified ‘arr’ at file scope
```

which I believe is what I'm looking for.

But when I compile exactly the same code with a command `gcc main.c` on my machine, the code compiles without an error and returned value is correct. Could someone explain where is my mistake?

My compiler version:

```
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: `gcc -std=c17 -pedantic-errors ...` otherwise will be using a variant of C named ["GNU C"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html) (which is Standard C plus extensions)

Comment: The standard "gcc" on MacOS is actually just a symlink to clang. Add the `-pedantic` flag and you will see "warning: variable length array folded to constant array as an extension". (And pick the appropriate language version.)

Comment: Then do I understand correctly that in newer C standard constant expressions behave similarly to those in C++?

Comment: And just out of curiosity - why put it as comment rather than an anwser? I could've been raining points for you

Comment: It's an extension allowed by C standard [6.6p10](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p10): "An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.". The only essential difference between normal arrays and VLA types is idiotic requirement for full evaluation of operand of `sizeof`.

Comment: Because VLA is a none-standard extension. ISO C++ doesn't recommend it. Use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> … the code compiles without an error…

(a) The C standard does not require compilers to issue diagnostic messages or to reject programs using forms of constants not defined by the C standard (or to reject programs with undefined behavior generally). The standard requires programs to issue a diagnostic message for violations of syntax rules and rules explicitly listed as constraints (per C 2018 5.1.1.3 1), but using `const` variables in an expression for array size is not such a violation. For other violations of “requirements” in the standard, the standard does not define what must happen (C 2018 4 2), and an implementation may accept such programs (C 2018 4 6).

(b) The C standard explicitly allows implementations to accept other forms of constant expressions (C 2018 6.6 10, “An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions”).

(c) [Testing with Clang 15.0.0 for ARMv8 on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xzozjPaKG) produces the message “variable length array folded to constant array as an extension [-Wgnu-folding-constant]” even with default compiler options. I do not have the Apple version of Clang 15.0.0 to test, so, if you do not see that message, this seems to be a difference in the Apple version. Adding the switches `-std=c18 -pedantic-errors` will likely cause the compiler to reject this code.

Comment: Thanks for thorough explanation, I didn't even realize that I'm asking 3 questions in just 1..

Comment: I couldn't however make Apple's Clan work, as even adding `-std=c18 -pedantic-errors` didn't make error to show. What I did instead is I replaced Apple Clang with Homebrew GCC.